# Git won't upload

Tags: git, github

When I add and commit files... I run these commands and git won't upload to server :/

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:bosnian/codeigniter-from-scratch.git
$ git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 364, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (358/358), done.
Writing objects: 100% (364/364), 2.01 MiB, done.
Total 364 (delta 122), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

this is where it ends..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your commits have been pushed, they do appear on your github page. (“*bosnian created branch master at bosnian/codeigniter-from-scratch about 4 hours ago*”) Perhaps there is a delay in github's mighty infrastructure? On download, I also get 122 deltas and 364 objects, therefore it must be there by now.

```
[...]
remote: Total 364 (delta 122), reused 364 (delta 122)
Receiving objects: 100% (364/364), 2.01 MiB | 1.12 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas:  65% (80/122)   
[...]
```